# Installing QGIS under Mint 18.2 (Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial)?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, linux-mint

**The problem**

Following the instructions from the QGIS page, after the corresponding ppa channels are installed, the command

```
 sudo apt-get install qgis
```

fails with a message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
qgis : Depends: python-qgis (= 1:2.18.18+24xenial) but it is not going to be installed
```

Trying again with:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
```

leads to the error:

```
python-qgis : Depends: python-qscintilla2 but it is not going to be installed
```

Finally, trying with:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis  python-qscintilla2
```

gives:

```
python-qscintilla2 : Depends: sip-api-11.3 but it is not installable
```

After some hours looking for a solution, I figured out that xenian only supports the sip-api-11.2. For some bizarre reason, QGIS packages point for the version 11.3, which does not exist in xenian, crashing the installation.

**The Fix**

Fortunately, a fix that worked on my machine was:

Download these individual .deb packages:

[python3-pyqt5.qsci](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/python3-pyqt5.qsci)

[python-qscintilla2_2.9.1+dfsg-4build1_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-qscintilla2)

The package python3-pyqt5.qsci will force the installation of sip-api-11.2.

Install these packages in that same order:

```
sudo gdebi python3-pyqt5.qsci_2.9.1+dfsg-4build1_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi python-qscintilla2_2.9.1+dfsg-4build1_amd64.deb
```

After this qgis should install normally.

```
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  It is permissible, and encouraged to post self-answered questions on this site, but here you have posted an answer within a question.  Please cut/paste your answer out from your question and into the area reserved for answers.

Comment: From https://qgis.org/debian-ltr/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages I see a dependency on sip-api-11.2; not 11.3. Did you install a newer version of python-sip manually? You should have `4.17+dfsg-1build1`.

Comment: Great! Works for me (Mint 18.3).